# How can set the page size of MigraDoc?

Tags: c#, migradoc

Sorry for I am just beginner of PDFsharp.

How can I set PageSize to a document? Let's say A4.  How to set it? Here it is my code. Thanks.

```
    Document document = new Document();

    // Add a section to the document
    Section section = document.AddSection();
    section.AddParagraph("dddddd");


    // Add a section to the document
    var table = section.AddTable();
    table.AddColumn("8cm");
    table.AddColumn("8cm");

    var row = table.AddRow();
    var paragraph = row.Cells[0].AddParagraph("Left text");
    paragraph.AddTab();
    paragraph.AddText("Right text");
    paragraph.Format.ClearAll();
    // TabStop at column width minus inner margins and borders:
    paragraph.Format.AddTabStop("27.7cm", TabAlignment.Right);
    row.Cells[1].AddParagraph("Second column");
    table.Borders.Width = 1;
```

Comment: Document = file, Section = group of pages, [etc](http://www.pdfsharp.net/wiki/MigraDoc_PageSetup.ashx).

Comment: MigraDoc is much like Word: you have a document with sections which contain paragraphs.

Comment: Yeah. That is what I was trying to looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A4 is the default size.

Every section has a `PageSetup` property where you can set page size, margins and such.

```
var section = document.LastSection;
section.PageSetup.PageFormat = PageFormat.A4;
section.PageSetup.TopMargin = "3cm";
```

You should never modify DefaultPageSetup, use a `Clone()` instead. `PageFormat` does not work for the `Clone()`, because `PageWidth` and `PageHeight` are set for the default size A4.
To get Letter format, you can use this code to overwrite `PageWidth` and `PageHeight`:

```
var section = document.LastSection;
section.PageSetup = Document.DefaultPageSetup.Clone();
section.PageSetup.PageFormat = PageFormat.Letter; // Has no effect after Clone(), just for documentation purposes.
section.PageSetup.PageWidth = Unit.FromPoint(612);
section.PageSetup.PageHeight = Unit.FromPoint(792);
section.PageSetup.TopMargin = "3cm";
```

To get Letter format, you can use this code to reset `PageWidth` and `PageHeight` to make `PageFormat` work again:

```
var section = document.LastSection;
section.PageSetup = Document.DefaultPageSetup.Clone();
section.PageSetup.PageWidth = Unit.Empty;
section.PageSetup.PageHeight = Unit.Empty;
section.PageSetup.PageFormat = PageFormat.Letter;
section.PageSetup.TopMargin = "3cm";
```

Creating a `Clone()` is useful if your code uses e.g. left and right margins to calculate table widths or such. No need to create a Clone if you set all margins explicitly or do not use margins for calculations.
If you need `Clone()` you can use the methods shown here to set the page size.

Comment: Thanks. You mean `section.PageSetup.PageWidth = "21cm";section.PageSetup.PageHeight = "29.7cm";` ? Can I ?

Comment: One question please . I found the AddTab have the different behavior between in the Table and Paragraph. AddTab in the table would make the content align right. like css `float:right`. But in the Paragraph it is not . just add a Tab as normal. Is that true ?Please help to clarify.

Comment: `AddTab()` is like pressing Tab in Word. The effect depends on the tab stops you have set for the paragraph. Tab stops can be left aligned, right aligned, centered, or decimal. Comments are not the right place to ask new questions. Also see this post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16775815/162529