# Want to remove big margin at top of legal page format

Tags: c#, pdfsharp, migradoc

I tried the code below in MigraDoc GDI 1.50.4000-beta3b and 1.32.4334.0. When I set the page size to legal format, it either doesn't get converted to legal format, or it leaves a big margin at the top, as if the page size was 8.5 x 11, and the extra length was inserted at the top of the PDF. I'd rather the text start at the top of the page. How can I get around this?

In the sample below, there is a large margin at the top.

```
// Create a new MigraDoc document
Document document = new Document();
//document.UseCmykColor = true;

// Add a section to the document
Section section = document.AddSection();
section.PageSetup = document.DefaultPageSetup.Clone();
section.PageSetup.PageFormat = PageFormat.Legal; //setting page size here didn't seem to work
section.PageSetup.TopMargin = "0cm";

// Add a paragraph to the section
Paragraph paragraph = section.AddParagraph();

paragraph.Format.Font.Color = Color.FromCmyk(100, 30, 20, 50);

// Add some text to the paragraph
paragraph.AddFormattedText(@"Hello World!", TextFormat.Bold);

#if GDI
// Using GDI-specific routines.
// Make sure to use "#if GDI" for any usings you add for platform-specific code.
{
}
#endif

#if WPF
// Using WPF-specific routines.
// Make sure to use "#if GDI" for any usings you add for platform-specific code.
{
}
#endif

// Create a renderer for the MigraDoc document.
PdfDocumentRenderer pdfRenderer = new PdfDocumentRenderer(true);

// Associate the MigraDoc document with a renderer
pdfRenderer.Document = document;

// Layout and render document to PDF
pdfRenderer.RenderDocument();

pdfRenderer.PdfDocument.Pages[0].Size = PdfSharp.PageSize.Legal;

// Save the document...
const string filename = "HelloWorld.pdf";

pdfRenderer.PdfDocument.Save(filename);
// ...and start a viewer.
Process.Start(filename);
```

Comment: Bad idea to set the page size after rendering the document. Does it work if you take the line `section.PageSetup = document.DefaultPageSetup.Clone();` out?

Comment: Thanks so much!!! That did the trick. Then why does this URL say "you should never modify DefaultPageSetup, use a Clone() instead"? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32757196/how-can-set-the-page-size-of-migradoc I also stopped setting the page size after rendering. That was just a shot in the dark to see if it resolved the issue

Comment: The point is: do not modify DefaultPageSetup. Modify the PageSetup of your section, with or without assigning a Clone of the DefaultPageSetup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`PageFormat` is used to set `PageWidth` and `PageHeight` if they are unset.

Invoking `section.PageSetup = document.DefaultPageSetup.Clone();` assigns both `PageWidth` and `PageHeight` with the values for A4 size. Changing `PageFormat` later has no effect on the effective page size which remains A4.

After invoking `section.PageSetup = document.DefaultPageSetup.Clone();` you have to set both `PageWidth` and `PageHeight` to the correct values.

`section.PageSetup = document.DefaultPageSetup.Clone();` is used to initialize all values of PageSetup. Use this if you use PageSetup to make calculations based on margins and such.

It is not generally recommend to invoke `section.PageSetup = document.DefaultPageSetup.Clone();`. It is strongly recommend to use a `Clone()` instead of making changes to the `DefaultPageSetup` directly.

Setting `PageFormat` works as expected if you do not assign the `Clone()`.